# angular - pattern and ng-model error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a mail field with pattern:

```
pattern="^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\']+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\']+)*)|(\'.+\'))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\']+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\']{2,})$"
```

and a directive that use `ngModel` on the same field:

```
   <input pattern="^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\']+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\']+)*)|(\'.+\'))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\']+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\']{2,})$" 
                        dir= "ltr"
                        class="form-control sgn-rounded_textbox" 
                        name="emailBox1" 
                        type="email" 
                        ng-model="vm.model.emails.emailField"
                        input-change = vm.mail>
```

inputChange directive:

```
    (function () {
        function inputChange($log, $timeout, $q, appCmdService) {

            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                require: 'ngModel',
                scope: {
                    inputChange: '='
                },
                link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                    var el = element[0];

                    if (checkForENSettings(scope)) {

                        if (ngModel) { // Don't do anything unless we have a model
                            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                                if(value){
                                    //some logic to change the value....
                                    ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
                                    // renders the input with the new viewValue
                                    ngModel.$render();
                                    //set cusor position
                                    el.setSelectionRange(start, end);
                                    //$log.log('ngModel.$parsers newVal', value);
                                    return value;
                                }
                            });
                            ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {

                                ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
                                // renders the input with the new viewValue
                                ngModel.$render();

                                return value;
                            });
                        }

                    }

                    function checkForENSettings(scope){
                        if(scope.inputChange && scope.inputChange.lang === 'en'){
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                }
            };     
}
        angular.module('common').directive('inputChange', inputChange);

    })();
```

The `input-change` works on any field without `pattern`, but when combaining them I get

```
Cannot assign to read only property 'message' of object '[object DOMException]'
```

Follwed by

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
```

Is there a way to use `ngModel` and `pattern` on the same `input` field?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that there is an issue with HTML5 `input type="email"` and getting Element `selectionStart` or `selectionEnd` known issue on - 
[HTML5 input email ans selection](https://github.com/firstopinion/formatter.js/issues/29).

Solved by removing `type="email"`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at ng-pattern and ng-modal-options?

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Comment: same result with ng-parrern.

Comment: and ng-model-options got nothing to do with the issue.